# Remove elements from beginning of array, which have certain value (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays

I want to remove elements from start of an array, but only certain value. For example, I want to remove all "1" from start of an array.

I want this array:
1,1,2,3,2,3,1,4,5

or this array:
1,1,1,1,2,3,2,3,1,4,5

to became this:
2,3,2,3,1,4,5

Note: There is one more "1", but not repeating on start of an array, I need that to remain in array. Only starting repetitive "1" should be removed.

One PHP line, without for, foreach or other loops, if possible. I know how to do this using loops. I want to know if there is another single line solution for this kind of problem.

Comment: If solution is not possible, just say it so... No need to "minus" me out... I have problem, not having an idea for a solution is not a reason for "minus"...

Comment: Please post code that you have tried

Comment: Like I said, I know how to do it using loop, but I am trying to figure it out how to make it happen in single line. Best I could do is:
`array_filter(array_diff($array,array("1")))`
but it remove all "1"...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little helper function that will achieve the task:

```
<?php

function recursively_remove_value_from_start_of_array($value, $arr) {

    while(true) {
        if( count($arr) > 0 && $arr[0] == $value )
            array_shift($arr);
        else
            break;
    }

    return $arr;

}

$arr = array(1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4);
$filtered_array = recursively_remove_value_from_start_of_array(1, $arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my try with loops. I don't think there is a one liner solution unless you create a function that does it for you.

```
foreach($array as $k => $v){
 if($v == 1) unset($array[$k]); else break;
}
```

Comment: OP wants to do this without using loops

Comment: @SaqibAmin like I said, I don't think there is a way to do it without loops unless you create your own function. This is the minimalist way to do it.

Comment: This is actually what I am doing now, only inside a function... If nothing else except loops is possible, this is the way.